# gmap app(.apk) not running in device(spice mi-720)android 2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator

i wrote a simple google map app,it runs fine with emulator on my pc but fails in "spice mi-720".
note-1)got the api key and wrote it at main.xml
2)make the .apk file using debug.keystore 
3)set the tab to allow non market app to install in settings

the apk is installed in the tab successfully but showing "the program is stopped unexpectedly".i have given the code snippet below.
pls help.

```
activity
--------
public class test extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}

 main.xml
 ----------
  <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map_view"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:apiKey="0SlULcexiGYLloibzAUWGXb5AeQHk7Lnnf365sQ" />       
</RelativeLayout>


 manifest file
 -----------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.tets"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".test"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the mapView in your activity

```
   MapView mp;
   MapController mc;
   GeoPoint gp;
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   MapView  mp=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
   mp.displayZoomControls(true);
   mp.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   double lat= 40.8;
   double longi =-96.6666;
   gp=new GeoPoint((int)(lat* 1E6), (int)(longi*1E6));
   mc=mp.getController();
   mc.animateTo(gp);
   mc.setZoom(14);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the spice mi720 tablet does not contain the google APIs. Android Devices on their own do not have the market app, the gmail app and some other apps, and they also do not include the google maps api. The google maps API is an add on that only phones and tablets get that are approved by google. Many cheap tablets are not approved by google.

Your App is crashing because it tries to load a class that is not available on the device. The only solution to this is to check if the maps framework is available and if it is not show an error message to the user or try to open a replacement using other map kits or a web based google maps solution.

Comment: i seek  more suggestions from you guys because i faced a lot of problems,if anyone can help plz................